# How to create multiple keys in keystonejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, keystonejs

How to create multiple keys in keystonejs

```
Photo.add({
eventsId: {type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'Event'},
mediaId: { type: String},

photo: { type: Types.Url }});
```

I want to set eventsId and mediaId to be the primary keys. How to do it? Thanks

Comment: There are several interpretations of what you might be after. In order of expected likelihood: are you trying to build [secondary indexes](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes) on those fields, a unique index on `eventsId` and `mediaId`, or do you actually want `eventsId` and `mediaId` to be a compound primary key (`_id` in the MongoDB document)?